# How to achieve interface polymorphism in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, oop

I have this interface hierarchy:

```
interface parent {
    common: string;
}

interface child1 extends parent {
    prop1: string;
}

interface child2 extends parent {
    prop2: string;
}
```

Now I want to have an interface, which one property is a `parent` interface, meaning it can be either child1 or child2.

I tried this:

```
interface SomeObject {
    member: parent;
}

let a: SomeObject = {
    member: {
        common: "a",
        prop1: "b"
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that `prop1` is not a member of `parent`.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common approach to this is to create a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types):

```
interface parent {
    common: string;
}

interface child1 extends parent {
    prop1: string;
}

interface child2 extends parent {
    prop2: string;
}

interface SomeObject<T extends parent> {
    member: T;
}

let a: SomeObject<child1> = {
    member: {
        common: "a",
        prop1: "b"
    }
}
```